# What are the required permissions for TFS to write to network drives

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2010

TFS requires a UNC drive to write to.  It requests this when we create/edit/queue a build.

\\server\share\

Many links on the internet suggest to direct this UNC location to the local server.

\\tfsserver\share\

Our setup requires that the builds be dropped to a different server, not the TFS machine.

\\otherserver\builds\

**What permissions are required for this UNC drive?**

Comment: Did you cerate a "service" account for the TFS processes?

Comment: Yes however the TFS host process runs as Network Service which seems to be the preferred config. That seems to expand to mydomain\servername$ which does have access to the UNC share and underlying folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Change and Read permissions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb778394

The real trick is assigning these permissions to the right account. If you used Network Service as the service account for Team build *and* the network share is on the same computer as the build service, you can just use "Network Service," assign Change and Read, and it'll work. If you used network service and your build machine and the network share are on *different* computers, you need to use this format: domain\buildmachine$

That's the domain of the build machine, followed by the name of the build machine and the $ symbol. Check out the MSDN topic above for specific instructions.